# Domain default changed

Tags: domain, terminal-server, remote

Somehow a few of our users default domain when logging into our remote terminal services has changed. How would this happen and how do I change everyone's default back to the domain not (this computer)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it may have been caused by a recent RDP update (I've seen a similar issue, but not looked into it in any detail).

You can set this key to your domain on your terminal servers:

**HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultDomainName**

Create the key if it does not exist or perhaps stick this into a batch file and in a computer start up script to ensure it's set

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /T REG_SZ /d YourDomain /f
```

Comment: How do you know I'm geni?

Answer (score 0):

You can force machines to default to any domain you like via Group Policy.

You need to set the following option in your Default Workstations Policy (you could actually set this in the Default Domain Policy if you want it to apply to all machines)

```
Computer Config
__ Policies
____Administrative Templates
______System
________Logon
__________Assign a Default Domain for Logon = Enabled (and type the Domain you want to default to)
```